# Is there a neater way to do this? Java IF

Tags: java

```
public void moveRowItemToBottomIfAllowed(int r, int f) {
    int i = rows[r].peek().getType();
    int j = 0;
    if (bottom[f].isEmpty()) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            if ((k == f) || (bottom[k].isEmpty()) || (bottom[k].peek().getType() != i)) {
                continue;
            }
            j = 1;
        }
        if (j == 0) {
            bottom[f].push(rows[r].pop());
        }
    } else if ((!bottom[f].isEmpty()) && (rankTrueFalse(rows[r].peek(), bottom[f].peek())) && (rows[r].peek().getType() == bottom[f].peek().getType())) {
        bottom[f].push(rows[r].pop());
    }
}
```

As I'm still learning java I've been putting together some rules for a game, I went through how to do it logically and came up with the above code which works correctly but it looks like a bit of a mess - is there any neater way or a more efficient way of writing this code? any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: _Only_ use i, j and perhaps k for tight for-loops over int-values.

Comment: Don't remove the code in the question so other readers can know what was asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would [*extract methods*](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) to make the code more readable. At first sight I would extract

- the `for` loop, or probably the whole contents of the `if` block,
- the expression from the 2nd long `else if`

Use descriptive names for your new methods (and for your variables too, for that matter). This makes a huge difference in readability.

Comment: +1 for extraction and descriptive names. Fundamentals of clean code, right there!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use more descriptive names for your variables. What is r? What is f? I'm guessing that f is some sort of numeric representation of the suit, since you compare it to k, which iterates over four values.

There might be more to say about the code overall, but the first step is to write the code in a self documenting manner.

Answer (score 1):

There are bits of expressions which could be extracted into local variables: `rows[r].peek()` and `bottom[f].peek()` being the most obvious ones.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using `j` as a flag. Booleans are better for that, but you can `return` early instead of setting the condition that guards the rest of the processing, getting rid of `j` entirely.

You're double checking that `bottom[f].isEmpty())` is `false`, and can use the already looked up `i` instead of repeating `rows[r].peek().getType()`

Both sides of your first condition, if they end up doing the processing, do the same processing, which you can write once:

```
public void moveRowItemToBottomIfAllowed(int r, int f) {
    int i = rows[r].peek().getType();

    if (bottom[f].isEmpty()) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            if (k == f) continue;
            if (bottom[k].isEmpty()) continue;
            if (bottom[k].peek().getType() == i) return;
        }
    } else {
        if (!rankTrueFalse(rows[r].peek(), bottom[f].peek())) return;
        if (bottom[f].peek().getType() != i) return;
    }

    bottom[f].push(rows[r].pop());
}
```

This code is then structured as a bunch of guards with early exits, followed by the processing.

The guards could then be extracted into their own method, leaving:

```
public void moveRowItemToBottomIfAllowed(int r, int f) {
    if (moveIsAllowed(r,f)) bottom[f].push(rows[r].pop());
}
```